# reseting filter on datatable to include full search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

working on from my previous Q

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550384/check-value-in-table-row-column


 val = 2
    get table.row[where val = data-uid]
    check next row
    if table.rows[data-uid = val] continue until it is not the same, when value is different pass back
    var newVal = ?
```

this all works but only for the first button click. on the second button click the table holds the value from the previous search as opposed to checking all the values in the jquery datatable. I tried reseting the filters but this didnt work...

```
t.fnResetAllFilters(false);
                //t.fnResetAllFilters();
                // t.fnFilter('');
```

so basically the first time round time round

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var elementsLength = elements.length;
```

elements.length returns a value ofd 10. but because currentElement returns 4 results the next time round elements.length only contains 4 results

```
loop1:
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
            {
                var currentElement = elements[i].getAttribute('data-uid');
                loop2:
                for (var j = i + 1; j < elements.length; j++)
                {

                    var nextElement = elements[j].getAttribute('data-uid');

                    if (currentElement !== nextElement)
                    {
                        rowId = elements[j].getAttribute('data-uid');
                        break loop1;
                        //return;
                    }
                }
            }
```